# Не удается установить Laravel через Composer

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

При установке Laravel через Composer пишет ошибку установки. Что может быть? В PATH вроде все прописал как должно быть... На одном компьютере такие же пути и все работает, laravel установился...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Забейте свои ошибки в переводчик и наступит просветление, а вообще без английского хотяб на уровне "понимаю со словарем" - далеко не уехать.

Comment: У вас же ясно написано, что нет прав на запись в папку куда хотите установить проект

Comment: Оно в любую папку не ставит. Ни на С ни на Д.

Comment: Я английский понимаю. Я вижу что оно пишет нет доступа. По какой причине и как дать доступ?

Comment: Есть ли у кого то еще варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить --prefer-dist:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravel
```